# JAVA Replacing line or strings in textfile not working

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

So i have made two methods that creates the file (createFile(); and one to fill the textfile with empty highscores if none are set.

```
public class HighscoreList {
static String highscore = null;
static PuzzleModel theModel;
static File file = null;
public static int nom;
public static int tu;
public static int nor;
public static String search = " ";
static String replace = "2";
static String numberOfRows = null;
static String timeUsed = " ";
static String numberOfMoves = " ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createFile();
    isEmptySetEmptyHighscore();
    // checkScore(0);
    getHighscore(0);
}

public static void createFile() {
    file = new File("C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Eclipse Workspace\\15Puzzle\\15Puzzle\\src\\FifteenPuzzle\\ScoreBoard.txt");
    System.out.println("Created file " + file.getName());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File didn't exist creating new file");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void isEmptySetEmptyHighscore() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Eclipse Workspace\\15Puzzle\\15Puzzle\\src\\FifteenPuzzle\\ScoreBoard.txt"));
        if (br.readLine() == null) {
            setEmptyHighscoreFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void setEmptyHighscoreFile() {
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        System.out.println("File is empty, fills with empty fields");
        for (int i = 3; i < 101; i++) {
            bw.write(i + ":" + numberOfMoves + ":" + timeUsed+"\n");
        }
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have a getHighscore() that reads the two empty " " fields with moves and timeUsed. It is currently able to read this, but i cant write to those empty spaces in the textfile and replace them with actual numbers that i want.
EDIT: With the replace command it just adds it to the bottom of the file.

Is there something wrong with my code that re erases the text that i try to replace or how do i do it?
I tried something like this:

```
public static void writeToFile(int rows) {
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Eclipse Workspace\\15Puzzle\\15Puzzle\\src\\FifteenPuzzle\\ScoreBoard.txt"));

        if(br.readLine().split(":")[0].equals(Integer.toString(rows+1))){
            bw.write(br.readLine().replaceFirst(rows+2+": : ", "yes"));
            System.out.println(" lel");
        }
        bw.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try this ?

```
 String line = br.readLine();
 if(line.split(":")[0].equals(Integer.toString(rows+1))){
        bw.write(line.replaceFirst(rows+2+": : ", "yes"));
        System.out.println(" lel");
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, but it adds to the bottom of the file.

Comment: Writing in append works only at the end of the file, if you would to replace a string inside a file you have to read before all the file , replace the value you want and the writing the entire content of the file